# A layman's question concerning vacuum genesis

Tags: energy, cosmology, energy-conservation, dark-energy

I would like to preface this by saying that my knowledge of physics is limited, so I apologize in advance if I confuse any terms.

I recently learned about vacuum genesis and zero-energy hypotheses.  I find both of these absolutely fascinating, but they bring to mind a significant question.  I've asked a related question elsewhere, and been told to consult books on the subject by Laurence Krauss and Brian Greene.  I intend to read those books in the future.

For now, though, is there a way to explain in less space than a book how the universe spontaneously appeared while still conserving energy, and why this process cannot happen again? If a region of space was spontaneously populated with an equal amount of energy and negative energy (expansion energy = dark energy?), what is to prevent this from happening again?

Answer (score 2):

> For now, though, is there a way to explain in less space than a book how the universe spontaneously appeared while still conserving energy, and why this process cannot happen again? If a region of space was spontaneously populated with an equal amount of energy and negative energy (expansion energy = dark energy?), what is to prevent this from happening again?

Even with 100 books, we do not currently have anything to write  but "We don't know for sure", on every page of them. We have lots of ideas which you can read about in popular science books, but imo, if you really want to know, you can't escape biting the bullet and learning mathematics. We are lacking in experimental data and new discoveries more than in ideas, but the ideas are based in math :)

Having said that, personally I think Lawrence Krausse's  are among the more rigorous of all the  popular science books. The very best of luck reading them.